# space between textboxes MVC5 & Bootstrap 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this situation with code:

```
@model MVC.Models.Parameters
@{
ViewBag.Title = "BigCalc";
}
<h2>Welcome to BigCalc!</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Calculator", FormMethod.Post))
{

<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.number1, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.number1, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.number1)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.number2, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.number2, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.number2)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.result, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.result, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.result)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Get sum</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

}
```

[image]

I want to add some more space between textboxes.
I know for `<br\>` but that isnt a fancy way.
Maybe to put `style=margin:bottom` or something like that.
Or to create a hidden div between them?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the Bootstrap example renders nicely, and you have copied the same html structure, I would check existing MVC template styles to see if something is overriding and eating up all of the margins.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at this solution [**Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lig1pE).

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but where is the css for that div?

Comment: Then I definitely have some "eating" issues, cause I can't see the bootstrap functionality..thanks anyway

Comment: @Stefan0309 I think so. Make sure your Bootstrap.min.css as well as the  bootstrap.min.js are fully loaded.